# Date Range Filter for PHP MySQL Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm a newbie in PHP and I just want to ask. How do I set a date range filter? I've tried tutorials - but they don't seem to work for me.

I do have this, but it has no functions. I'm trying to implement this in a CRUD table.

```html
<form role="form" action="index.php" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input placeholder="Filter From" class="col-sm-2"  type="text" id="from" name="from">
    <input placeholder="To" class="col-sm-2"  type="text" id="to" name="to">
    <input style="padding-bottom:0px" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="go" value="filter range">
    </div>
</form>
```

and for the date picker, I use this.

```html
<script>
$(function(){

    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate:"+lw",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths:3,
        onClose:function(selectedDate){
            $("#to").datepicker("option","minDate",selectDate);
        }
    });

    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth:true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function(selectedDate){
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The PHP table, I'm trying to implement this on..

```html
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "appointments");  
 $output = '';  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM appointments ORDER BY id DESC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
 $output .= '

      <div class="table-responsive">

           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                     <th>Select</th>  
                     <th width="10%">Id</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Name</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Email</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Address</th>  
                     <th width="10%">phoneNumber</th>  
                     <th width="10%">appointmentTime</th> 
                     <th width="10%">appointmentDate</th> 
                     <th width="50%">message</th> 
                     <th width="10%">delete</th>

                </tr>';  
                             if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                             {  
                                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
                                  {  
                                       $output .= '               

                    <tr id="'.$row["id"].'"> 

                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="'.$row["id"].'"></td>
                     <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                     <td class="name" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["name"].'</td>  
                     <td class="email" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["email"].'</td>
                     <td class="address" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["address"].'</td>  
                     <td class="phoneNumber" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["phoneNumber"].'</td>  
                     <td class="appointmentTime" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["appointmentTime"].'</td>  
                     <td class="appointmentDate" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["appointmentDate"].'</td>
                     <td class="message" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["message"].'</td>
                     <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger                                               btn_delete">Delete This Row</button></td>
                </tr>  
              ';  
      }                           

 }  
 else  
 {  

      $output .= '<tr><td colspan="10">Data not Found</td></tr>';  
 }  


 $output .= '</table>
<div align="center"> 
<button type="button" name="delete" id="delete">Delete</button>
                </div>  
      </div>   ';  
 echo $output;

 ?>
```

Comment: You have to change your sql statement according to you selected dates. Tip: Use the keyword BETWEEN.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the value of your date range, so that you can range your appointment date based from the date range inputed.

try this one!

PHP :

```
<?php

//get date range value
if (isset($_GET['go'])) {

   $date_from   = $_GET['from'];
   $date_to     = $_GET['to'];
}
```

SQL :

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM appointments 
            WHERE appointmentDate 
            BETWEEN  '$date_from' AND '$date_to'
            ORDER BY id 
            DESC";
```

Comment: Hello po, iwhen adding the SQL statement you posted, my data disappears.

Comment: What is your date  field name in your database ?
change "appointmentDate" in SQL query into your table field name from your database.

Comment: try this one!
format the date that equals format into database date.
`<?php
//get date range value
if (isset($_GET['go'])) {
   $date_from   = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_GET['from']);
   $date_to     =date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_GET['to']);
}`

Comment: The code returns an internal server error. Also, my date is already in yyyy-mm-dd